# What is the fastest way to serialize a DataFrame besides to_pickle?

Tags: python, serialization, numpy, pandas, pickle

I need to serialize DataFrames and send them over the wire.  For security reasons, I cannot use pickle.

What would be the next fastest way to do this?  I was intrigued by msgpacks in v0.13, but unless I'm doing something wrong, the performance seems much worse than with pickle.

```
In [107]: from pandas.io.packers import pack

In [108]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000, 100))

In [109]: %timeit buf = pack(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.5 ms per loop

In [110]: import pickle

In [111]: %timeit buf = pickle.dumps(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 241 µs per loop
```

The best I've found so far is just serializing homogenous numpy arrays (df.as_blocks() was handy) using array.tostring() and rebuilding the DataFrame from them.  The performance is comparable to pickle.

However, with this approach, I am forced to convert columns of dtype=object (i.e., anything with at least a string) to be entirely string since Numpy's fromstring() cannot deserialize dtype=object.  Pickle manages to preserve mixed types in object columns (it seems to be including some function in the pickle output).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now pretty competetive with this PR: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5498 (going to merge for 0.13 shortly)

```
In [1]: from pandas.io.packers import pack

In [2]: import cPickle as pkl

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000, 100))
```

Above example

```
In [6]: %timeit buf = pack(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 492 µs per loop

In [7]: %timeit buf = pkl.dumps(df,pkl.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
1000 loops, best of 3: 681 µs per loop
```

Much bigger frame

```
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100000, 100))

In [9]:  %timeit buf = pack(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 192 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit buf = pkl.dumps(df,pkl.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
10 loops, best of 3: 119 ms per loop
```

Another option is to use an in-memory hdf file

See here: http://pytables.github.io/cookbook/inmemory_hdf5_files.html; no support yet in pandas to add the driver arg (could be done by pretty simply by monkey-patching though).

Another possibity a `ctable`, see https://github.com/FrancescAlted/carray. Not supported yet in pandas ATM though.

Comment: Many thanks Jeff.  I patched the open() method in HDFStore.  For the sizes I will typically use, I still see a big difference between in-memory to_pickle() and in-memory to_hdf().  Another suggestion someone made was to reuse the __reduce__ and __setstate__ methods myself.  Do you know how I can go from the __reduce__ return value back to an object?

Comment: if the difference between picklie/in memory hdf actually matters then you are down to function calls, which is not worth optimizing. just take the frame apart and use numpy.tostring. dealing with small vs bigger size are 2 different problems. if you want to learn more about reduce you will have to dive into the code.

Comment: I updated...take a look at the PR I posted. this should basically solve the problem.

Comment: This is fantastic.  Thanks so much, Jeff.  (Are you jreback?  If so, thanks for all your work on pandas.)  I'd messed around with np.array.tostring(), but it doesn't handle dtype=object nicely.  In general, do you think the msgpack format is going to continue to get love from pandas?

Comment: yep..that's me....i put the msgpack in originally (wes had cythonized it providing the impetus). I think its going to be pretty useful going forward. That is the idea, essentially a 'replacement' for pickle.

Comment: And how do you unpack?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to serialize it using a binary file format to save tabular data which is written in Cython for performance: [BinTableFile](https://pypi.org/project/bintablefile/). Project Github: https://github.com/eSAMTrade/bintablefile